# How to remove cache images if they not in used in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, cache, catalog, image

i need to create new script if the image not present in real folder and not in used than delete from cache folder

example

> ```
> Cach folder image
>
> pub/media/catalog/product/cache/2a584e14ed2061ee0dac7db2e52f28f9/1/_/1_asc-d-404-mn_dollcarrier_minnie_2000.jpg
> ```
>
> "pub/media/catalog/product/1/_/1_asc-d-404-mn_dollcarrier_minnie_2000.jpg"
>
> if this image not present in => "pub/media/catalog/product/"
>
> than delete from => "pub/media/catalog/product/cache"

this kind of script i need to create can any one help me how can i archive this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to take a backup for the media folder and there is a way to delete unused images is using a module. Here is one that you can use. It is not risk-free, so do a backup first. You can use it from Github free.

reference: https://jvmsaas.com/support-en/magento-2-delete-unused-product-images-without-extension

Github : https://github.com/Vendic/EAVCleaner

Comment: can this module delete images from cache folder ?

Comment: I did not try but you can check that module from the above link and check useful commands there.